# Wrapping response with API route handlers

Tags: next.js

I have been thinking on the security implications of storing a JWT in localstorage, and I thought of an idea but I'm not sure if this is optimal or not, say I have an API that returns a JWT as part of a json body: `{token: ....}`. Now because my original REST API is not setting any cookie could I do that in an API Route in Next JS? (or should I):

```
default function handler(req, res) {
// do original call here 
//manipulate response, set httpOnly cookie with jwt
...
}
```

Comment: You can use HttpOnly cookie for authentication with Nextjs API routes, because with Next your app and API are served by the same server. Note though that HttpOnly cookies are inaccessible from your client code.